# Python for loop: "list index out of range" error?

Tags: python, for-loop, prime-factoring

I have a code, based on problem 3 from Project Euler: "The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29. What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?"

I have a code below that I thought would work, but line 9 (`for k in range(2,res[j]):`) keeps returning the error: "IndexError: list index out of range". It doesn't seem like I'm modifying my list as I move through my for loop, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

```
def find_primes(num):
    res = []
    print(num)

    for i in range(2,num):
        if num%i==0:
            res.append(i)

    for j in res:
        for k in range(2,res[j]):
           if res[j]%k==0:
               res[j]=False
    list(filter((False).__ne__, res))

    m = max(res)
    return(m)
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Your code doesn't have correct indentation . please correct it so we can help you!

Comment: because `res[j]` goes to the `j`th item in `res`, and `res` has numbers larger than it's length.

Comment: You should review a tutorial on looping constructs.

Comment: @Arman right, thank you!

Comment: `(False).__ne__`... what are you trying to do? because this is not the way

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to do:

```
for j in range(len(res)):
    for k in range(2,res[j]):
```

Using `for j in res` will iterate over `res` elements.

Comment: You mean `for j in range(len(res)):`

Comment: You're right, I wasn't thinking. Thank you so much for your help!